# How to port my code from golang to kotlin?

Tags: go, kotlin, key-value

I'm very new to kotlin so I'm bit confused to convert some part of my code to golang. I have a json like,

```
{
  "w" : "a",
   "x" : [
       {
          "y" : "b",
           "z" : 0
        },
        {
          "y" : "c",
          "z" : 1
        }
     ]
}
```

and I want to put the values of x in a `map<String, Any>`. In golang I had stored the unmarshalled content in "data" which is a `map[String]interface{}`.

```golang
fmt.Printf("Results: %v\n", data)
```

The output of Results was

```
w=a
x=[{y=b,z=0}, {y=c,z=1}]
```

then I accessed only the interface{} part of data which I again converted to `map[string]interface{}`

```kotlin
    s:=reflect.ValueOf(data["y"])
    for i:=0;i<s.Len();i++ {
        map1 := s.Index(i)
        x := map1.Interface().(map[string]interface{}) //cast
        n := x["y"].(string)
        m := x["z"].(float64)
        map1[n] = m
    }
```

when I print the map1 values

```
y=b
z=0

y=c
z=1
```

In Kotlin I am able to get till
`w=a x=[{y=b,z=0}, {y=c,z=1}]`

I am not able to do the remaining part in Kotlin - Intellij.

here is the full code

````
I want to convert this whole code to kotlin ```package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "reflect"
    "sync"
)

//func to read the API's body
func getRespo1() {
    // json data
    url:=<url>
    res, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    //read the API's body
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    bs := []byte(body)
    var data map[string]interface{}

    //Unmarshaling the body
    err = json.Unmarshal(bs, &data)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Printf("Results: %v\n", data)
    fmt.Println("W:",data["w"])
    fmt.Println("X:",data["x"])

    //convert the array to display value
    s:=reflect.ValueOf(data["x"])
    for i:=0;i<s.Len();i++ {
        map1 := s.Index(i)

        //convert to map[string]interface{}
        x := map1.Interface().(map[string]interface{})
        xx := x["y"].(string)
        zz := x["z"].(float64)
        //storring in globally declared map
        charac_map[xx] = zz
    }
}

//globally declared map
var charac_map = make(map[string]float64,15)

//main function
func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    //goroutines to run APIs in parallel
    go func(){
        getRespo1()
        wg.Done()
    }()
    wg.Wait()

    //Display content of the map in console
    fmt.Println("CONTENT OF MAP")
    for j, v := range charac_map {
        fmt.Println(j, v)
    }
    handleRequests()
}

//handle function for localhost
func handleRequests() {
    http.HandleFunc("/somethin/", printcontent)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}

//function to return the value of query request in encoded json
func printcontent(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Something:")
    reqBody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Error")
    }

    //creating query request
    keys, ok := r.URL.Query()["key"]
    if !ok || len(keys[0]) < 1 {
        log.Println("no key found")
        return
    }
    //storing map's key to query key
    key := keys[0]
    v := charac_map[key]
    json.Unmarshal(reqBody, &v)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(v)
    log.Println("URL key ",key)

    //print message in console everytime localhost is hit
    fmt.Println("Endpoint Hit: homePage")
}
````

Comment: Could you paste your code?

Comment: @p1gd0g Please take look. I have pasted whole code.